# How should I calculate a net value after a BTC withdrawal from an exchange?

Tags: exchanges, buy-bitcoins, exchange-rate, arbitrage

Many exchanges have a withdrawal fee (such as Poloniex, which charges customers in 0.0005 BTC on average) and these fees are mostly for network costs.

Should I consider as a general rule that the net value of a cryptocurrency withdrawal is `amount - withdrawal fee - network fee` or just `amount - (withdrawal fee OR network fees)` if an exchange doesn't have these fees explicit?

Comment: I think your 'general rule' is probably correct in most cases, but ultimately you're asking about the policy of a business, not some rule inherent to the function of the bitcoin network/protocol.

Comment: oh sure, definitely not about bitcoin network, but more about what is the done thing